# Copy value of above row in 1st column for rows matching pattern

Tags: awk, sed

Suppose I have a | separated text file like this:

```
123|col 2 row 1|col 3 row 1
xxx|col 2 row 2|col 3 row 2
xxx|col 2 row 3|col 3 row 3
789|col 2 row 4|col 3 row 4
xxx|col 2 row 5|col 3 row 5
xxx|col 2 row 6|col 3 row 6
```

Using `sed` or `awk` how to get this:

```
123|col 2 row 1|col 3 row 1
123|col 2 row 2|col 3 row 2
123|col 2 row 3|col 3 row 3
789|col 2 row 4|col 3 row 4
789|col 2 row 5|col 3 row 5
789|col 2 row 6|col 3 row 6
```

If value of column 1 is 'xxx' it should be replaced with value in above row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {if ($1=="xxx") $1=p; else p=$1} 1' file
123|col 2 row 1|col 3 row 1
123|col 2 row 2|col 3 row 2
123|col 2 row 3|col 3 row 3
789|col 2 row 4|col 3 row 4
789|col 2 row 5|col 3 row 5
789|col 2 row 6|col 3 row 6
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'N;s/^(([^|]*).*\n)xxx/\1\2/;P;D' file
```

Append the next line to the current line and if that appended line begins `xxx` replace that string by the first field of the current line. Print/delete the current line and repeat.